# Dictionary Definition in Pythod has syntactical error

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using Python 3.6  I am trying to create a nested dictionary object.  This is my definition.   When I run the script, I get a syntactical error, show below.

```py
        DATA_INFO = {'file1_info': {
                   'filename'   : 'Datafile1_' + str(yyyy),
                   'file_ext'   : 'xls',
                   'active'     : 'Y',
                   'calc_idx'   : '1,4',
                   'inc_columns': '1,2,11',
                   'indexes':
                     {'name': 'ZAXDR',   'active': 'N', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'},
                     {'name': 'ZAXLP',   'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'},
                     {'name': 'ZAXERNL', 'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'},
                     {'name': 'ZAXERNS', 'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'}
                  },
                 'file2_info': {
                   'filename'   : 'Datafile2_' + str(yyyy),
                   'file_ext'   : 'xls',
                   'active'     : 'Y',
                   'calc_idx'   : '1,4',
                   'inc_columns': '1,2,11',
                   'indexes':
                     {'name': 'ZAX', 'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'}
                  }
                }
```

I get this error when I try and run the actual script:

```py
        {'name': 'ZAXLP',   'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'},
#                                                                                                        ^
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I'm not able to spot the issue.

Comment: What's with the `<pre>` tags? Can you clean up your input here please.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a `list` to store more dicts for a key :

```
'indexes':
     [{'name': 'ZAXDR',   'active': 'N', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'},
      {'name': 'ZAXLP',   'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'},
      {'name': 'ZAXERNL', 'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'},
      {'name': 'ZAXERNS', 'active': 'Y', 'idx_type': 'domestic', 'data_row': 9, 'multi_benchmark': 'N'}]
```

Comment: Ok....so, if I make the inner part a list, can I still access by key?   "name", "active", "idx_type".    I'll need to do this.    Also, I'm trying to figure out how to loop through all of this.   Many thanks!!!

Comment: You can access by key but you have to look in a list, if this solves your issue you can accept the answer or to upvote, thx!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.   Was wondering if you could help supply me with some code, like some 'for' loop, which would iterate through the list and print the key / value pairs of the "indexes" portion.    I'm not having push luck.    I can loop through the "file1_info" section, and get those values, but when I get to "indexes", I am getting stuck........many thanks!

Comment: like I said you can accept this answer, and ask another question, thx!